# Why are many object files linked instead of one large object file?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, object-files

Why is it that compiled programming languages (C++ for example) are set up to create **many object files** that are linked together as opposed **one large object** being created?

For example (written in C++, could apply to any compiled language), consider two files in a project `main.cpp` and `auxiliary.cpp`. What is the difference between `main.cpp` and `auxiliary.cpp` being compiled to `main.o` and `auxiliary.o` and then linked to `main.exe`, and `main.cpp` with a `#include auxiliary.cpp` being compiled to only `main.o` and linked to `main.exe`? To my knowledge, these would at least *superficially* produce the same result.

I see the necessity for multiple objects in the case of multi-language projects, but not otherwise. Does multiple objects somehow give the linker more flexibility in creating an executable?

Comment: How would you find anything in a single cpp file that was several hundred thousand lines long containing thousands of classes? Also when I change 1 line I would not want to wait 1 hour to compile.

Comment: Using the `#include` preprocessor command, the source would be in many files to the user, but appear as one file to the compiler.

Comment: That would suffer from unnecessarily long compile times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate compilation units like this make compiling faster. If you make a change in `auxilliary.cpp`, the compiler only needs to recreate `auxilliary.o` rather than recompiling everything. This becomes especially important the larger the project is.

Comment: This is a naive and wrong answer. In fact good optimization will always do the opposite

Comment: @Lothar Will you be more specific with your suggestion? What's wrong with my answer? Will editing `auxilliary.cpp` require compiling other files? And when you say "do the opposite", the opposite of what exactly? Feel free to post your own answer if you have some knowledge that will help others.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this with a rhetorical question: Why do you write many functions instead of one big one?

The same logic applies at the link level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *one* big binary you just need to build a static *library*, but that is not the object code from one translation unit, but from many.

Now consider whether what you are asking really makes sense: If it was to create a single .o file, it would have to merge the results of the compilation of each cpp into that binary as it proceeded building, effectively paying the cost of linking multiple times. Furthermore, a change to one translation unit would require that the compiler figured out which of the symbols in the large object file came from the original version of this translation unit, remove those from the object and add the new ones after rebuilding.

Comment: Well you could at least try to group into different libs. The question is if libs provide more linking information or just reduce with file system access. Don't want to look at the AR  source code for that